# Best practice for publishing an open source project with third party dependancies

Tags: open-source

I am about to publish a project to codeplex. My question is what the best approach is for 2 third party libraries that my project depends on. The one is System.Data.Sqlite and the other is Dapper. Should I put the specific binaries that I built against into the repository which would allow the user to get the code and run without getting other dependancies, or should they just be mentioned in the documentation as requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the CodePlex community handles this typically. I can just speak in general.

Normally you do not publish binaries in a open-source code repository.
Typically Windows binaries are published as parts of releases, most times as an installer package. In this package you would include all binaries your executable depends on.

Note that if you do already publish a binary (your own software) it makes much more sense to also provide the dependencies. Think about the worst case of a user trying your binary with a slightly, but not fully compatible binary he built from the third-party sources, and obtaining erratic behavior.

One thing you have to note is however that if you publish third-party software, you also have to adhere to their **license**. In the example of the GPL that means that you need to ship some relevant documentation and offer to provide the source files used to build these binaries on request.
So in some cases it is much easier to just not ship them.